# Openwrt changing ip segment

Tags: networking, openwrt

I've bought a wrt3200 and I've put openwrt on it.

The wrt gets an ip (wan port, xx.xx.1.x) from  the dhcp of the isp router.

The setup: inet---isp_router--wrt---client.

isp_router: dhcp enable, no bridge mode possible.

Wrt: dhcp enable, brigde mode enabled by default

I like to set lan port of the wrt to xx.xx.2.x segment, so I can separated the clients from the isp router.

I've unplugged the wrt to set the lan  to 2.1, but, I get the following error. "Settings can not be apply, starting with rollback procedure" and the wrt stays with an 1.1 ip.

Anyone an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Unplug wan port from wrt
2. Config wrt to x.x.2.x segment
3. Assign manually ip to your pc
4. Plug the wan port of your wrt

Your wrt has now an x.x.2x.ip